# Dispatch doesn't update component instantly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

For reference I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZfCVq5iCBw) tutorial. My trial app is a user management tool. Which currently shows a list of users below is the store code. It succesfully adds a user to the list using `dispatcher.dispatch({type: "CREATE_USER", name: "Andrew"})`. However it doesn't do so till I click on a route then it updates.

```
    import { EventEmitter } from "events";

    import dispatcher from "../Dispatcher";

    class UserManagement extends EventEmitter{
        constructor(){
            super();
            this.users =
                [
                {
                    id: 1234,
                    name: 'Anton',
                    email: 'escalante.anton@outlook.com'
                },
                {
                    id: 12345,
                    name: 'Bacon',
                    email: 'bacon@me.com'
                }
                ];
        }
        getAll(){
            return this.users;
        }
        createUser(name){
            const id = Date.now();
            this.users.push({
                id,
                name,
                email: 'default@email.com'
            });
            this.emit("change");
        }

        handleActions(action){
            switch(action.type){
                case "CREATE_USER":{
                    this.createUser(action.name);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    const userobj = new UserManagement;
    dispatcher.register(userobj.handleActions.bind(userobj));
    window.dispatcher = dispatcher;

    export default userobj;
```

**EDIT** I'm thinking I need to trigger a state change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To re-render the data you should trigger the render by either calling setState or forcing rendering using forceUpdate

*Note that forceUpdate is **not recommended***, correct way for your component to read store data is to copy data into state and read from this.state in the render function.

http://blog.andrewray.me/flux-for-stupid-people/

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I checked the tutorial git repo and reviewed the code I found a setState command that he didn't include in the video tutorial. Thanks for reaffirming my suspicion.